# kendo web ui grid batch editing on click of custom command using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, web, grid, kendo-ui

I would like to enable batch edit on click of custom button in toolbar. Let's say I have button called "Edit" in toolbar. On click of Edit button, I would like to activate all rows for editing. I do not want to make all rows editable initially on load.

Is this possible? If yes, can somebody give direction on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try like this,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true} },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true} }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                navigatable: true,
                pageable: true,
                height: 430,
                toolbar: ["Edit", "create", "save", "cancel"],
                columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 110 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 90}],
                editable: false
            });


            $('.k-grid-Edit').on("click", function () {

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    navigatable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 430,
                    toolbar: ["Edit", "create", "save", "cancel"],
                    columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 110 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 90}],
                    editable: true
                });

            });
```

Comment: Did not work, instead gave invalid argument error in kendo.web.min.js. I am trying to use like below, var cashMgmtGrid = $("#cashMgmtGrid").data("kendoGrid"); cashMgmtGrid.options.editable = true;cashMgmtGrid.refresh();...still no luck

Comment: People having problems with adding custom button, check this link, http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/toolbar-with-custom-button.aspx

Comment: Show me your code. So i can help you.Because this is working perfectly on my project.

Comment: i have lots of custom editors (dropdown list) in the grid, so I am doing $("#cashMgmtGrid").empty(); and then initializing grid again. Still work in progress, will post answer once ready. I referred this link, http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/change-grid-editable-at-runtime.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Inline with @Jaimin solution I propose a similar approach where you have two grids but you don't create a new Grid each time you commute from edition to not edition mode (not sure if this is a requirement).

So what I do is creating two grids, exactly the same definition and just differ in that one is hidden and one is visible, one is editable and one is not. When you click on the button, it hides the visible and shows the not visible. Since both share the same DataSource it actually works perfect because changing page in one changes in the other, editing one, updates the other.

So, it is something like:

1- A CSS definition used for toggling visibility:

```
.ob-hide {
    display : none;
}
```

2- A DataSource definition:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
        read : {
            url: ...
        },
        update : {
            url: ...
        },
        create : {
            url: ...
        },
        destroy : {
            url: ...
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            id : ...,
            fields: {
                id       : { type: '...' },
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Next the two grids:

```
$("#grid-editable").kendoGrid({
    editable: "inline",
    dataSource : ds,
    ...
}

$("#grid-not-editable").kendoGrid({
    editable: false,
    dataSource: ds,
    ...
});

$("#grid-editable").addClass("ob-hide");
```

And finally the button handler that commutes grids:

```
$("#make-editable").on("click", function() {
    $("#grid-editable").toggleClass("ob-hide");
    $("#grid-not-editable").toggleClass("ob-hide");
});
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/bCEJR/